# Spring ControllerAdvice not being called on exceptions

Tags: spring, exceptionhandler

Though I defined ControllerAdvice to handle exceptions, I dont see that being invoked.
Here is my code, could you please advice

```
    public class RestError {   
        private String code;
        private String message;

    public RestError(String code, String message) {
        this.code = code;
        this.message = message;
    }

    public String getCode() { return code; }

    public String getMessage() { return message; }
}
```

```
public class RestException extends RuntimeException {

   private String errorCode;
   private String errorMessage;

    public RestException(String errorCode, String errorMessage) {
        super(errorMessage);
        this.errorCode = errorCode;
        this.errorMessage = errorMessage;
    }

    public String getErrorCode() {
        return errorCode;
    }

    public void setErrorCode(String errorCode) {
        this.errorCode = errorCode;
    }

    public String getErrorMessage() {
        return errorMessage;
    }

    public void setErrorMessage(String errorMessage) {
        this.errorMessage = errorMessage;
    }
}
```

ControllerAdvice

```
@Controller
public class RestController {

    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(RestController.class);
    @RequestMapping(value = "/echo", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
    public void echo(@RequestParam(value = "clientVersion", required = false) String clientVersion,
                     @RequestParam(value = "applicationName", required = false) String applicationName,
                     HttpServletRequest httpRequest) {
        LOG.info("Throwing exception...");
        throw new RestException("9999", "Invoke Exception Handler");
    }
}
```

I see that spring is creating GlobalExceptionHandler object but its not being invoked.
Here is [Full code](https://github.com/jconsultant88/exception-advice)

I am using Spring 4.3.0 framework and running in jetty container through maven.
Please help me

Comment: Try adding `@ControllerAdvice(basePackageClasses = RestController.class)`

Comment: No luck@pvpkiran

Answer (score 0):

You need to add

```
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
```

to your xml to enable the ControllerAdvice.
Also don't forget to add the namespace and schema definition for this

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">
```

Comment: @venu88 I'm glad it worked. In that case [please accept it as an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).